# Printing job status only once based on the status

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I would like to ask a more theoretical question. I'm trying to add a new feature on a working program which is written in Java. The purpose of the program is to run multiple jobs in the background and check their status. The status could be `"Ready", "Waiting", "Running", "Stopped", "Done"`. I would like to create a method which will print some information to the output, which is based on the status of the running jobs. The rules for the printing:

- For the first time of checking the job, it should print: `"Started: " + job.getName()`.
- If job is stopped it should print `"Failed: " + job.getName()`.
- If job is done running it should print `"Done: " + job.getName()`.

In the job class I declared two variables:

```
private boolean startDisplay = false;
private boolean endDisplay = false;
```

I did a loop through all jobs and check their status and print the proper message for each case. Also, I updated the variables to be true.  But the problem is it prints the same string over and over. So I made those variables static:

```
private static boolean startDisplay = false;
private static boolean endDisplay = false;
```

But, in this way it will print `start` and `end` for only one job (and not for the others).
How can I print every message only once? I thought of using the hashmap but it does not feel the right `OOP` way.

Comment: may you are running the loop multiple times?

Comment: in which class are you running the loop and can u paste code here. your problem is not clear.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Thanks for the comment. It exits the loop when the jobs are either done or failed.

Comment: Please show your code. You can use `Set` for each status to store names of jobs that were already printed and shouldn't be printed anymore.

Comment: @TTaJTa4 what if multiple jobs have same status, that could be the case for gettin same string.

Answer (score 0):

From What I guess you need a POJO class something like following :

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class Job {
    private String jobName;
    private boolean startDisplay = false;
    private boolean endDisplay = false;
    private boolean doneDisplay = false;

    public Job(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }

    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }

    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }

    public boolean isStartDisplay() {
        return startDisplay;
    }

    public void setStartDisplay(boolean startDisplay) {
        this.startDisplay = startDisplay;
    }

    public boolean isEndDisplay() {
        return endDisplay;
    }

    public void setEndDisplay(boolean endDisplay) {
        this.endDisplay = endDisplay;
    }

    public boolean isDoneDisplay() {
        return doneDisplay;
    }

    public void setDoneDisplay(boolean doneDisplay) {
        this.doneDisplay = doneDisplay;
    }
}
```

And a Class to manage your POJO :

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            jobs.add(new Job("Job" + (i+1)));
        }

        String prompt = "";
        while (!prompt.equals("q")) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            prompt = scanner.nextLine();
            if (prompt.equals("q"))
                System.out.println("Bye");

            if (prompt.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Checking Job1 " + jobs.get(0).getJobName());
                System.out.println("Started: " + jobs.get(0).isStartDisplay());
                System.out.println("Done: " + jobs.get(0).isDoneDisplay());
                System.out.println("Finished: " + jobs.get(0).isEndDisplay());
                System.out.println("Changing State of the job....");
                jobs.get(0).setStartDisplay(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare the boolean variables with the `volatile` keyword. Otherwise the main thread will not reliably see the changes made by the other threads.

Comment: Just making them volatile doesn't do any magic to it's program.